# How to prevent a tag from refreshing page using knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have this html code when user click on link on collapsible  sidebar nav it refresh the all page and reload viewModel  but it will reset the collapsible sidebar. I think it is because of the parent div has  ata-bind="click: clickEventTypeButton" just want to ask how can I prevent event bubbling in link and refreshing  using KOjs

```
<div class="toolbar-options cursor-hand" data-bind="click: clickEventTypeButton">
    <label>Event Type</strong>
</div>
<div class="toolbar-secondary-options initial-state" data-bind="fadeVisible: isEventTypeSelected">

    <a class="menuItem" data-bind="attr: {href: eventTypeLink}">
        <div class="toolbar-options cursor-hand">
            <strong>Event Types</strong>
        </div>
    </a>


    <a class="menuItem" data-bind="attr: { href: programLink }">
        <div class="toolbar-options cursor-hand">
            <strong>Programs</strong>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: explain your point of view?

Comment: my code in the office I will be try it first thing in the morning

Comment: Not clear on the context. if you click a link a page will reload, which resets your page and therefore the viewModel as well. It sounds like you want to maintain the state of the the collapsible sidebar between pages?  If so you might want to consider cookies or passing values in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Knockout will allow the click event to continue to bubble up to any higher level event handlers.

For example, if your element and a parent of that element are both handling the click event, then the click handler for both elements will be triggered.

Since the href its child of sidebar, when you click on the href the 2 click handler will be triggered, so you need to use `clickBubble: false` on the slide bar

Check [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html), **note 4**

Comment: is it ok to use clickBubble: false" in a tag ?